# Why does Python print my string with quotes and commas?

Tags: python-3.x, string, variables, integer

So when I run the following code:

```
x = 4
y = 'the value', x, 'is truthy'
print(y)
```

I don't understand why my output is :('the value', 4, 'is truthy')

For example, if I simply print this exact line of code directly:

```
print('the value', x, 'is truthy')
```

Not really a critical problem, I was able to use the format function to avoid the problem V

```
def truthy_or_falsy2(arg):
    if arg: 
        return f'The value {arg} is truthy'
    
    return 'The value {arg} is falsy'
```

Appreciate the advice!

Comment: In your `y` assignment statement you have inadvertantly used the syntax for creating a tuple on the right-hand side of the assignment operator - you can tell by checking the type of `y`. Try instead, `y = "the value " + str(x) + " is truthy"`

Comment: Just reviewed tuples, still learning this whole Python thing. I think that makes sense then. So is it a true statement to say that the format method is the only way to easily place an integer within a string? I know you can use the str() function but without doing that, is this the only way?

Comment: Yes, format strings ("f strings") are probably the most popular choice for creating strings from mixed-type expressions since they were introduced in Python 3.6 (see [Python 3's f-Strings: An Improved String Formatting Syntax (Guide)](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/))

Comment: Alright, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you write `y = 'the value', x, 'is truthy'`, you are setting y to be a tuple, as you are setting it to multiple values separated by commas. For it to be a simple string, you can use concatenation:
`y =  'the value '+ str(x) + ' is truthy'`
or string formatting: 
`y= 'The value {0} is truthy'.format(x)`
The reason this issue does not arise when you write it directly into a print statement like `print('the value', x, 'is truthy')` is the way that function parameters work: each comma separated value is passed as another argument into the function, and the print statement simply prints each argument out. So when you write it like this, each comma separated item is treated as a different item and printed, rather than all placed in a tuple which you are then printing out as a whole when you assign it to a variable such as in `y = 'the value', x, 'is truthy'`

Comment: Thank you very much for the in depth reply. This makes sense the way you explained it. I guess I have used print in tutorials so frequently, I forget that it's a function like anything else and separation by commas has a different meaning or purpose as opposed to when I was setting it to the variable y. Thanks again!